# Just Mock, Mocking not working as expected

Tags: c#, unit-testing, model-view-controller, justmock

I am new at Just Mock, facing a problem to pass this method, need help to understand the issue.

I have a following code that I want to test

```
public ActionResult Create(JournalViewModel journal)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newJournal = _mapper.Map<JournalViewModel, Journal>(journal);// Mapper Updates cause syntax change

            newJournal.UserId = (int)_membershipService.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

            var opStatus = _journalService.AddJournal(newJournal);
            if (!opStatus.Status)
                throw new System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError));

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
            return View(journal);
    }
```

and following code that I have written for testing

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void Create_return_journal()
    {

        var userMock = Mock.Create<MembershipUser>();
        Mock.Arrange(() => userMock.ProviderUserKey).Returns(1);
        Mock.Arrange(() => membershipService.GetUser()).Returns(userMock);

        var opStatusMock = Mock.Create<OperationStatus>();
        opStatusMock.Status = true;
        Mock.Arrange(() => journalService.AddJournal(Mock.Create<Journal>())).Returns(opStatusMock);


        //Act
        PublisherController controller = new PublisherController(journalService, membershipService, mapper);
        ViewResult actionResult = (ViewResult)controller.Create(Mock.Create<JournalViewModel>());
        var model = actionResult.Model as JournalViewModel;

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(model);

    }
```

over here I am expecting opstatus.Status to be true but getting false everytime, which results it to go in

```
if (!opStatus.Status)
                throw new System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError));
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Done. just in case if somebody looking for answers.

I forgot to Mock Mapper.

Below is the code that I have used to solve this issue.

```
 [TestMethod()]
    public void Create_return_journal()
    {
        var journalNew = Mock.Create<JournalViewModel>();
        var journal = Mock.Create<Journal>();
        Mock.Arrange(() => mapper.Map<JournalViewModel, Journal>(journalNew)).Returns(journal);

        var userMock = Mock.Create<MembershipUser>();
        Mock.Arrange(() => userMock.ProviderUserKey).Returns(1);
        Mock.Arrange(() => membershipService.GetUser()).Returns(userMock);

        var opStatusMock = Mock.Create<OperationStatus>();
        opStatusMock.Status = true;

        Mock.Arrange(() => journalService.AddJournal(journal)).Returns(opStatusMock);

        //Act
        PublisherController controller = new PublisherController(journalService, membershipService, mapper);
        RedirectToRouteResult actionResult = (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.Create(journalNew);


        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult);

    }
```